# Generate link with two input fields

Tags: java, javascript, html, textfield

I have Two Input Fields

Field1 and Field2

I want to generate a external link when clicking submit button

e.g. of the link as follow,

www.mystie.com/field1 + sometext + field2

---

I need this formula to use with Google map direction

Answer (score 0):

user `request.getParameter( "field1" )` in your action servlet

```
String link = request.getParameter( "field1" ) +"sometext" + request.getParameter( "field2" );
```

where your html is

```
<form action="myServlet" method="post">
  <input name="field1"/>
  <input name="field2"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String link = String.format("www.mysite.com/%s/sometext/%s",field1.getText(),field2.getText());
```

Comment: Is this javascript? ?%s, or special library?? Because this is first time I see it

Comment: It's Java. The question is unclear as to where the link will be formed exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to do so.

Try this

```
function submitclick(){
var text1=  document.getElementByID("feild1").value;
var text2=  document.getElementByID("feild2").value;
document.getElementByID("submitbuttonATag").href=text1+sometext+text2;

// Finally when the link is modified generate click
document.getElementByID("yourA_tag").click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery

```
("#submitButton").click(function(){
var url="www.mysite.com/";
url= url + $("#feild1").val();
url = url + "sometext";
url = url +  $("#feild2").val();
//Then use your url
 });
```